# Test for difference of coefficients in two logit regressions

Tags: logistic, regression-coefficients

I have the following problem. I have a sample of $n$ observations and divide it into two non-overlapping subsamples with size $n_1$ and $n_2$ correspondingly. Then I run logit regression for both subsamples:
$$\ln{\frac{p}{1-p}} = \alpha + \beta_1\cdot A + \beta_2\cdot B + \beta_3 \cdot C + e_i$$

At the end of the day, I obtain estimators for my regression. But what I need to do is to find out whether my $\beta_1$ coefficients are significantly different for two subsamples I have or not. I'm a bit confused about the test I could implement to deal with this issue. I thought about $t-test$, but due to the nonlinearity of the logit model, I can't use, if I understand it correctly. So, I suppose that I need to use the Wald test. I would be very pleased if you could help me to specify the Wald test for it. I know that 
$$W = n((\hat{\beta_1} - \beta_1)\hat{I}(\beta_1)(\hat{\beta_1} - \beta_1) )\to \chi^2,$$
but I don't clearly understand how could I use it for two different subsets. Regularly I code in R, so any practical code recommendations are welcomed.

The problem here, at least as I see it, with information matrix $\hat{I}$. I assume that when we have two subsets without any overlapping, we may represent it in block-diagonal way:
$$\hat{I} = \begin{pmatrix} A & 0 \\ 0 & B \end{pmatrix},$$
where $A = Var(\beta_1^{n_1})$ and $B = Var(\beta_1^{n_2})$. Moreover, I suppose that in such case I should multiply each block on corresponding number of observation, so $n_1$ and $n_2$ respectively. But, we have that differences on both sides of information matrix are scalars, while information matrix is matrix. So, this way is for sure not feasible.

Comment: Well I think that the easiest way to deal with it is to construct dummy variable for one of the subsamples and add an interaction term into the regression

Comment: Hi: Hottelling developed a test for testing the difference of the coefficients in two different regression models.  Maybe his test could be modified for your logistic case ? It was so long ago when I looked at it that I don't remember the name of the paper. If I can dig it up, I will send you the title.

Comment: Hi I found it and there's free access. Don't be thrown by the fact that it from Annals. I remember it actually being readable. :). I hope it's relevant to what you're doing. https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aoms/1177731867

Comment: Thank you, I will read it and try to find something useful. Practically, adding an interaction term solves my problem. So up to now, it's more about curiosity)